How to configure Better Auth's DrizzleAdapter to generate Supabase-compatible UUIDs?
I'm building a Next.js application using Better Auth for authentication and Supabase as the database. Better Auth is generating UUIDs in a non-standard format (KZMw0N5rJhdi_i1JbWle6), but Supabase requires UUIDs in the standard format (50928f86-1dbc-4b4a-8377-c83c81051f7c). This is causing user creation to fail with the error: "invalid input syntax for type uuid".
I attempted to override the UUID generation in the DrizzleAdapter configuration:
drizzleAdapter(db, {
    provider: "pg",
    generateId: () => TEST_UUID
})

But received a TypeScript error: "Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'generateId' does not exist in type 'DrizzleAdapterConfig'"
I also tried setting a default UUID in the database schema:
id: uuid("id").primaryKey().default(sql`'${TEST_UUID}'::uuid`)

But Better Auth generates its ID before reaching the database layer.
Better Auth should generate or accept UUIDs in the format: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

If you're on v1, you can use the advanced.generateId option instead in your auth config. You can also return false if you prefer the database to generate the ID.
